# Question for SO or SU?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, superuser, specific-question, scope

I'm seeking information on how to repackage Bazaar VCS to something as small as, say, the non-Tortoise version of Mercurial.

Should I ask this on SU or on SO?

Comment: FYI: If you dissociate and re-associate your SU account to your Meta account, you get 100 bonus rep here.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Now I can vote up questions and answers here on Meta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the question pertains to reducing the number of files needed for a Bazaar installation, I think this might be a better candidate for SU. Hopefully no more movement is necessary.